# how to find sub total for each T1 & T2 using Formula in Crytal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

[See This images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V5V8.png)

how to find sub total for each T1 & T2(see abv img link) using Formula in Crytal Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution:

1. select the Amount field
2. choose Insert | Summary...
3. select 'Sum' from the Calculate this summary pick-list (if not already chosen)
4. choose the Tenant field from the Summary pick-list

Follow these steps a second time to create a 'grand total' (a summary field located in the report-footer section).

If you insist on doing it the hard way, the formula would be:

```
// {@the_hard_way}
Sum({table.Amount},{table.Tenant})
```

Comment: if i want to find sub total & total separately for Commercial & Residential using Running Field & Formula Formula Fields,.what to do

Comment: Add a group on the Types field.